# Shiny DataTable Error: DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Requested unknown parameter '4' for row 0

Tags: r, shiny, datatables

I was updating a Shiny app I built some months ago and found some very strange behavior with the table output. Essentially each cell now contains a single character, not the string or full numeric it should contain).

This example reproduces the problem minimally.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Reproducible Example"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("minprice", label = "Minimum diamond price", 
                        min = 326, max = 18823, value = 1000)
        ),
        mainPanel(
           dataTableOutput("table"),
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    data(diamonds)
    diamond_filt <- eventReactive(input$minprice, {
        diamonds %>%
            filter(price >= input$minprice)
    })
    output$table <- renderDataTable(diamond_filt(), 
                                    options = list(pageLength = 10))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This also gives me the error pointed out in the title, which redirected me to [a datatables manual page](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4). But I still couldn't figure out what is wrong.

This code used to work (because it worked in the app), does anybody know what's going on?

Comment: I have shiny 1.4.0. I'll try downgrading to see if it works

Comment: So, using the implementations in the `DT` package seems to fix it also. i.e. if I use `DT::renderDataTable` and `DT::dataTableOutput`, it works fine.

Comment: Seems like there's some bug in this very specific case.

Comment: Yes this is correct see https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2653